# Differentiation of $(u(t),v(t))_{L^2(\Omega)}$ when $u, v \in H^1(I\times \Omega)$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I=(0,\infty)$. Consider $u, v \in L^2(I;H^1(\Omega))$ with $u_t, v_t \in L^2(I;L^2(\Omega))$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded doamin.

Is it true that
$$\frac{d}{dt}(u(t),v(t))_{L^2(\Omega)} = (u'(t), v(t))_{L^2(\Omega)} +(v'(t), u(t))_{L^2(\Omega)} $$
pointwise a.e. $t$?

I know it is true when we work in a Gelfand triple $V \subset H \subset V^*$ and we work in the space $W(V,H) = \{ u \in L^2(I;V) \mid u_t \in L^2(I; V^*)\}$. But we don't here, and I cannot find a reference. A reference to this would be a appreciated.

Comment: But $L^2\subset(H^1)^*$, so in fact $u_t,v_t\in L^2(I;H^1(\Omega)^*)$ and you can use your result. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta $L^2 \subset (H^1)^*$ is only true when we identify $L^2$ with its dual and work in a Gelfand triple setting. I don't want to do that. I think the equality holds by approximation but I really just want a reference to it.

Comment: I don't really understand your objection.  The Gelfand triple setting seems to apply perfectly here, and anyway you should be able to read your Gelfand triple proof and specialize it line-by-line to your setting.  But if you want a reference, I believe there are some results of this kind in Wloka's book *Partial Differential Equations*.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is inappropriate since I am using $H^1(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\Omega)$ in many different contexts (in the same proof) and there is no way on earth that I should take the Gelfand identification. I checked the Wloka but alas it does not contain it. Yes the proof I am sure is almost identical... I guess I'll just have to say so instead of referencing.